# Bing Maps - PhpStorm/JetBrains - Libraries

Tags: libraries, phpstorm, code-completion, bing-maps

I want to add the BingMaps AJAX 7 library to my libraries in PhpStorm 7.1.2, so that I can use code completion, highlighting, navigation, and documentation lookup

The problem is, that I can't download the BingMaps libary to include it to the libraries in my project, so there is no code completion at all. Any ideas?

Currently I only include the BingMaps in my index.html with following URL:

- https://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0

But the output of this URL isn't a library to download... it seems to be another type of interface.

Answer (score 0):

The Bing Maps control reference loads in several additional files. There is not local copy of the library that you can download. Hosting a local copy is against the terms of use and usually doesn't work. Unfortunately there is no supported way to do what your looking to do. Intellisense does work great with Bing Maps in Visual Studios. Visual Studios does support PHP as well. But I doubt you want to change your development environment just for this.

Comment: @ rbrundritt: Thank you for your reply! Yes, changing IDE only because of bing maps isn't my next choice, so I started to create a Stub for Bing Maps and it works for the main parts quite good.